# Why does Uninstall force IIS, Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, iis, installation, uninstallation

My .NET solution in Visual Studio 2008 has

1. ASP.NET website project
2. web deployment project for website
3. Custom actions library
4. web setup project

I can build setup and install it. However, during uninstall on my development machine (Windows 7), I am asked to close Visual Studio before uninstall can proceed.

On preprod server (windows web server 2008 R2), during uninstall user is asked to stop the IIS worker process - which is definitely not desirable.

Is there any way I could prevent uninstall to do this?